# Setting some field's value in DB

Tags: sql-server

In my SP What I want is that when a new Question is added, Active should be set to **false**. When I add new record, it gets added to the table in my DB but Active is getting set a **True**! What could be wrong ?

Comment: Could be a trigger, could be a default constraint, could be you're not calling the sproc you think you are. Put SQL profiler on it to find out more about what's happening. Think this is almost certainly a SQL question though, not really a C# one.

Comment: There's no default constraint on Active column and this Stored proceedure only is being called thats why rows are getting added in the table ..just this Active's value is getting set to True...still can't figure out why..

Comment: too much empty space in this code. its unreadable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How would I solve this:
1. Double-check table for defaults, triggers
2. Profiler, check exactly what params are passed to SP
3. Remove/comment out update part leaving only unconditional insert
4. Howl in agony and throw keybord out of the window

Answer (score 1):

Split your procedure into 2 seperate SPs, 1 for Insert and 1 for Update: easier to read, easier to debug (and should show where your problem is quickly)